# Activation of network failed with my VPN

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I have a problem with my vpn when I want to activate it, it was working fine until today.
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and my vpn is an L2TP vpn.

I reinstalled the VPN several times but impossible I always have the same errors, in the syslogs too.

```
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1676487754.0452] vpn-connection[0x55f412ad8580,538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707,"Selectour",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 88451
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1676487754.0594] vpn-connection[0x55f412ad8580,538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707,"Selectour",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1676487754.0678] vpn-connection[0x55f412ad8580,538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707,"Selectour",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu nm-l2tp-service[88451]: Check port 1701
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88462]: Redirecting to: systemctl restart ipsec.service
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec...
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu whack[88466]: 002 shutting down
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu ipsec[88471]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu libipsecconf[88471]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu systemd[1]: ipsec.service: Succeeded.
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec.
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec...
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu addconn[88475]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu libipsecconf[88475]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu _stackmanager[88478]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu libipsecconf[88478]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu _stackmanager[88483]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu libipsecconf[88483]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu ipsec[88740]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu libipsecconf[88740]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu ipsec[88738]: nflog ipsec capture disabled
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec.
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu libipsecconf[88755]: warning: could not open include filename: '/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf'
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88756]: 002 listening for IKE messages
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88756]: 002 forgetting secrets
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88756]: 002 loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88756]: 002 loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets"
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: debugging mode enabled
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: end of file /run/nm-l2tp-538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707/ipsec.conf
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: Loading conn 538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: starter: left is KH_DEFAULTROUTE
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" modecfgdns=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" modecfgdomains=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" modecfgbanner=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" mark=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" mark-in=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" mark-out=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" vti_iface=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" redirect-to=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" accept-redirect-to=<unset>
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" esp=aes128-sha1,3des-sha1!
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: conn: "538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707" ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: opening file: /run/nm-l2tp-538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707/ipsec.conf
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: loading named conns: 538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 1, has_peer = 1
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 1, has_dst = 1
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst  via 192.168.1.254 dev enp3s0 src  table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: set nexthop: 192.168.1.254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst  via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp2s0 src  table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 169.254.0.0 via  dev enp3s0 src  table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.17.0.0 via  dev docker0 src 172.17.0.1 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.18.0.0 via  dev br-3b8f59f5dec5 src 172.18.0.1 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.19.0.0 via  dev br-0c4ea6a9581e src 172.19.0.1 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.20.0.0 via  dev br-03bfdb4a48e9 src 172.20.0.1 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev enp3s0 src 192.168.1.29 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.0 via  dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.1.81 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 127.0.0.0 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 127.0.0.1 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 127.255.255.255 via  dev lo src 127.0.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.17.0.1 via  dev docker0 src 172.17.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.17.255.255 via  dev docker0 src 172.17.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.18.0.1 via  dev br-3b8f59f5dec5 src 172.18.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.18.255.255 via  dev br-3b8f59f5dec5 src 172.18.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.19.0.1 via  dev br-0c4ea6a9581e src 172.19.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.19.255.255 via  dev br-0c4ea6a9581e src 172.19.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.20.0.1 via  dev br-03bfdb4a48e9 src 172.20.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 172.20.255.255 via  dev br-03bfdb4a48e9 src 172.20.0.1 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.29 via  dev enp3s0 src 192.168.1.29 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.81 via  dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.1.81 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.255 via  dev enp3s0 src 192.168.1.29 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.255 via  dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.1.81 table 255 (ignored)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: seeking_src = 1, seeking_gateway = 0, has_dst = 1
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: dst 192.168.1.254 via  dev enp3s0 src 192.168.1.29 table 254
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: set addr: 192.168.1.29
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu nm-l2tp-service[88451]: Could not establish IPsec connection.
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[88761]: seeking_src = 0, seeking_gateway = 0, has_peer = 1
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu nm-l2tp-service[88451]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1676487754.7600] vpn-connection[0x55f412ad8580,538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707,"Selectour",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1676487754.7621] vpn-connection[0x55f412ad8580,538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707,"Selectour",0]: VPN service disappeared
Feb 15 20:02:34 R1-ubuntu NetworkManager[792]: <warn>  [1676487754.7630] vpn-connection[0x55f412ad8580,538229dd-c240-4f90-a931-051a685fb707,"Selectour",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

If anyone has a solution

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a log from when it worked?

Comment: no i don't have log when it worked sorry

Comment: You seem to be using libreswan, but with network-manger-l2tp IPsec phase 1 and 2 settings for strongswan (i.e libreswan doesn't use an exclamation mark).  Try removing the phase 1 & 2 settings. Probably also do a `sudo apt purge libreswan`, Then reinstall either libreswan or strongswan.